# Include Multiple Search Terms in an HTML Request

Tags: html, r, web-scraping

I found this post over here that shows how to search for news articles on Google using R:[Scraping Google News with Rvest for Keywords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65520315/scraping-google-news-with-rvest-for-keywords)

This post shows how to search for a single term, for example: `keyword <- "https://news.google.com/rss/search?q=apple&hl=en-IN&gl=IN&ceid=IN:en`"

- Can this above code be modified to search for multiple terms? For example, suppose if I want to search for news articles that contain BOTH "iphone" and "covid":

Could I write the query like this?

```
library(tidyRSS)

#I have feeling that "IN" stands for "India" - if I want to change this to "Canada", I think I need to replace "IN" with "CAN"?

keyword <- "https://news.google.com/rss/search?q=apple&q=covid&hl=en-IN&gl=IN&ceid=IN:en"

# From the package vignette

google_news <- tidyfeed(
    keyword,
    clean_tags = TRUE,
    parse_dates = TRUE
)
```

Is this correct?

Thank you!

PS: I wonder if there is a way to restrict the dates between which the search will be performed?

Comment: `hl` is `language` and `gl` is `country`

Comment: @ akrun: thank you so much for your reply! Would this be correct?

Comment: Also, for multiple words, you can use either `OR` or `AND`

Comment: Here: "https://news.google.com/rss/search?q=appleANDq=covid&hl=en-CAN&gl=CAN&ceid=CAN:en ?

Comment: Try `keyword <- "https://news.google.com/rss/search?q=apple%20AND%20covid&hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US:en"`

Comment: @ akrun: thank you so much! Do you know if there is a way to restrict the dates for the search?

Comment: What about `keyword <- "https://news.google.com/rss/search?q=apple%20AND%20covid+after:2022-03-01+before:2022-06-02&hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US:en"`

Comment: @ akrun: thank you so much for all of this - if you were to submit this as answer, I would approve it as the official answer. thank you so much - your code worked wonderfully!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For multiple items, if we want either of them use `OR` or if both needs to be present use `AND`.  Similarly, the `hl` stands for `language`, and `gl` for `country`.  In addition, for date ranges, use keyword `before/after`

```
library(tidyRSS)
keyword <- "https://news.google.com/rss/search?q=apple%20AND%20covid+after:2022-07-01+before:2022-08-02&hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US:en"
google_news <- tidyfeed(
    keyword,
    clean_tags = TRUE,
    parse_dates = TRUE
)
```

-checking for the date ranges

```
library(dplyr)
> all(between(as.Date(google_news$feed_pub_date), 
   as.Date("2022-07-01"), as.Date("2022-08-02")))
[1] TRUE
```